# Run queries in parallel python

Tags: python, pandas, oracle

I need to run select query In parallel in python

To run Multiple queries at the same time, I read about session pool and multiprocessing options but did not find clear example for it.

I want to create at least 2 connection and make it run at same time with different statments to double the speed because each task take 7 minutes now

Code is something like this

```
import cx_Oracle
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
uid="XYNERGY_BGR"
pwd="Bangal0r3"
service="BGRDB"
db = cx_Oracle.connect(uid + "/" + pwd + "@" + service)
cursor = db.cursor()
q=[“select * from AGENT_MAIN where agent = 1",
“ select * from table2”,
“ select * from table20”]

for n in q:
cursor.execute(n)

workbook = Workbook('outfile.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for r, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        sheet.write(r, c, col)
```

Comment: Were you looking for [_executmany_](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.executemany)? Did you want to do it in pandas?

Comment: executemany dose not work with select

Comment: @tdelaney `executemany` executes a single prepared statement passing pareters in batch, not many statements. And single connection cannot  execute multiple statements simultaneously

Comment: Unless your case is very specific, I would suggest reviewing your need to run queries in parallel. Why do you need to do so? If it's to query data from two tables, you could use a join statement (if they share an index/column). Asking to run two queries in parallel, given you only do selects, is smelly). Can you provide us with more details about your use case?

Comment: @CrispyHoliday actually I will make it save each query in different sheet I don’t think join will help. And I want it to run all queries at same time

Comment: Even if you were able to set up result fetching in parallel (with either python's parallelisation mechanism), I doubt that you may set it up to create a workbook with multiple sheets in parallel. At least native Excel app cannot do this

Comment: @astentx thanks for your comment. In this case it’s ok to save it in different files if I find the way

Comment: Here's one example of using a connection pool: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/how-to-use-python-flask-with-oracle-database  Also see the cx_Oracle samples https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/main/samples . If you want to run multiple SQL statements in parallel, you will need to run each statement in its own connection.

Comment: @ChristopherJones thanks for your reply. I can’t find in parallel example in GitHub if you can tell me the name of it ava  . And sorry but how can I implement connection for each query . Connection pool or what

Comment: See https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/connection_pool.py  The Flask example in the web page can be easier to understand if you are not familiar with threads.  Each web request (which can be in parallel) gets a connection from the pool and executes some SQL.